# can not access NIFI UI?

Tags: apache-nifi

Always can access UI until today!
[image]

show logs,why error of other server would make NIFI UI can not be accessed!?

1

```
2020-04-25 14:59:53,546 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-41] o.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL PutSQL[id=c1451287-2ee5-397e-9842-5e477212e954] Failed to update database due to a failed batch update, java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (ISA.PHY_ASSET_CLASS_X_PHY_ASSET_MAPPING_FK1) violated - parent key not found
. There were a total of 1 FlowFiles that failed, 0 that succeeded, and 0 that were not execute and will be routed to retry; : java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (ISA.PHY_ASSET_CLASS_X_PHY_ASSET_MAPPING_FK1) violated - parent key not found

java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (ISA.PHY_ASSET_CLASS_X_PHY_ASSET_MAPPING_FK1) violated - parent key not found
```

2

```
IOError: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException

org.python.core.PyException: null
```

3

```
2020-04-25 14:59:58,537 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-94] o.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL PutSQL[id=d9733768-de43-17b7-0000-00007453720b] Failed to process session due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
```

4

```
ERROR [MasterListener-mymaster-[10.148.xxx.xx:26379]] redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool Lost connection to Sentinel at 10.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx. Sleeping 5000ms and retrying.
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Maybe there are many other error...
ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED!

Comment: WORKED throuth seting the parameter regarding ```conntroller serviese open automatically``` to false but can not  find out  the relationship of entering nifi UI and error emited by other servers?

Comment: What is in nifi-user.log at the same time that you get the "unexpected error has occurred" ?